# How large space will be occupied by mysql for a varchar utf8 column?

Tags: mysql, character-set, varchar, utf-8

> Tip: To save space with UTF-8, use VARCHAR instead of CHAR. Otherwise, MySQL must reserve three bytes for each character in a CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8 column because that is the maximum possible length. For example, MySQL must reserve 30 bytes for a CHAR(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 column.

From:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html

Does this mean if I use a **varchar utf8** column other than **char utf8** column in mysql, mysql will physically store characters using 1 byte for latin  and 3 bytes for CJK(Chinese、japanese、Korean) ？

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CHAR(...) CHARACTER SET utf8` <strike>always</strike> takes 3 bytes per character -- `CHAR(100)` occupies 300 bytes (no length needed).  [The "ROW FORMAT" impacts the details of this statement.]

`VARCHAR` occupies 1-2 bytes for a length, plus only as many bytes as needed.  So `VARCHAR(100)` with `hello` will occupy 7 (2+5) bytes in any character set.

`Señor`, in `CHARACTER SET latin1`, take 5 bytes (plus length).  In utf8, it takes 6 bytes (plus length).  This is because `ñ` is the 1-byte hex `F1` in latin1 or the 2-byte `C3B1` for utf8.

Some Chinese characters and some Emoji, need 4 bytes, so `utf8mb4` is a better choice for them.

There is very little use for ever using `CHAR` instead of `VARCHAR`.  They are usually for consistent-length fields such as postal code, country code, md5, uuid, etc.  And all of those may as well be `CHARACTER SET ascii` or possibly `latin1`, but not `utf8`.

Back to your question...  With `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or utf8mb4):

- English letters take 1 byte.
- Western European accented letters take 2 bytes.
- Greek, Hebrew, and other languages in that general area, take 2 bytes.
- Japanese and Korean take 3 bytes.
- Most Chinese characters are 3 bytes; some are 4 and need utf8mb4.
- [A longer list](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#diagnosing_charset_issues)

"mysql will physically store characters using 1 byte for latin and 3 bytes for CJK" is *not* phrased correctly.  Change 'latin' to 'English' to make it correct.  ('Latin' tends to include various accented characters.)